# Compare each value of a Series against every other value from another Series in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Consider i have two pandas dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['r_no'] = [1,1,1,2,3,1,1,1,2]
df['user'] = ['sam','sam','sam','sam','peter','jack','jack','Kris','peter']
df['value'] = [76,76,7,8,8,2,29,2,8]
df['cam_id'] = ['ab','abc','ab','ab','ab','abcd','abcd','abcd','ab']

df_2 = pd.DataFrame()
df_2['r_no'] = [1,3,2,2,4,1,1,3,2,5,7,2,8,9,3]
```

```
df
   r_no   user  value cam_id
0     1    sam     76     ab
1     1    sam     76    abc
2     1    sam      7     ab
3     2    sam      8     ab
4     3  peter      8     ab
5     1   jack      2   abcd
6     1   jack     29   abcd
7     1   Kris      2   abcd
8     2  peter      8     ab

df_2 
    r_no
0      1
1      3
2      2
3      2
4      4
5      1
6      1
7      3
8      2
9      5
10     7
11     2
12     8
13     9
14     3
```

Expected Output
A new column in df dataframe

```
df['count_greaterandequal']
0     3
1     3
2     3
3     7
4    10
5     3
6     3
7     3
8     7
```

to calculate the number for 
**r_no** in *df---dataframe* has been **equal to or greater than** in 
*df_2---dataframe*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use broadcasted numpy comparison on the underlying arrays for performance.

```
df['count_greaterandequal'] = (df.r_no.values >= df_2.r_no[:, None]).sum(0)

df
   r_no   user  value cam_id  count_greaterandequal
0     1    sam     76     ab                      3
1     1    sam     76    abc                      3
2     1    sam      7     ab                      3
3     2    sam      8     ab                      7
4     3  peter      8     ab                     10
5     1   jack      2   abcd                      3
6     1   jack     29   abcd                      3
7     1   Kris      2   abcd                      3
8     2  peter      8     ab                      7
```

Comment: Can you explain me the None part with why sum not count @coolspeed

Comment: @andjkd that's the "broadcasted" part. Every element is compared with every other element, and you get a boolean mask, where True == 1 and False == 0. So sum the True elements which is the same as counting them.